# AngularJS facing trouble to understand clone object and reference assignment

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am facing problem in AngularJS 1.6
There are some confusions. 
I am iterating an array of objects named `aList` which contains mutable objects in HTML part.

```
<div ng-repeat="item in aList>
   <a ng-click = "updateDataFun(item)">Click</a>
</div>
```

Now in controller I have this

```
constructor(){
    this.updateData = {};
}
updateDataFun(item){
   // this.updateData = Object.assign({}, item); // this solve the issue. 
   this.updateData = item; 
}
cancelUpdate(){
   this.updateData = {}
}
```

Now, on a modal, I have something like that `<input ng-model="updateData.name">`

If I change anything (name, an attribute of updateData) via modal and press `cancelUpdate()` the changes reflect to `aList` array.

Here are some questions:

1. At `updateDataFun(item)` method, the assignment is reference assignment (assume). Am I right? So that, if I change on `this.updateData` via modal, it reflects `item`. Also, change `aList` index value where the `item` associated to.
2. If so then on `cancelUpdate()` invocation, `this.updateData` will be  `{}`. **Why does this not reflect `item`?** **It should be `{}`**.

However, if I uncomment `this.updateData = Object.assign({}, item);` and comment `this.updateData = item;` then it is working.

Comment: @Claies, Tnx. I have changed it.

Answer (score 2):

javascript passing object by reference and not by value
so this line is your issue:

```
this.updateData = item;
```

this line pass the **item** by reference so all the changes you will be make for this variable will be affect the source list item.
suggested solution is to copy the object instead of pass it by reference
like this :

```
this.updateData = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(item)); // create new item in the memory and assign it to updateData variable
```

you can use any other cloning method you want 
or create new object with only the values you need

**Edit**
sorry missing your questions,

1. you right as explained before,
2. when you write

   variable = {}
   the meaning is that your not changing the reference of variable to empty object, 
   you assign new (and empty) object to the variable (and not to the reference of the object)

hopes its help

Answer (score 1):

As suggested by yaron, your assumption that `this.updateData` has a reference to the individual `item` from `aList` is correct. Thus, when you change a property of `this.updateData` anywhere (even in a modal, if the modal receives a reference as well), it is reflected to the list.

However, in `cancelUpdate()` you assign an empty object in place of that reference (you replace the `item` reference with a reference to something else). The reference to `item` is broken thus any change from that time on (including the assigning of an empty object) is not reflected. If you want to assign `{}` to `item` you have to update the list directly or mutate the `item` object directly (not reassign).

`this.updateData = Object.assign({}, item)` clones the item to a brand new object and stores its reference to `this.updateData` thus any changes will again not be reflected to `item`.